# Dúvida Select Oracle - Duas condições

Tags: banco-de-dados, oracle, select

Tenho esse select, onde retorna em uma coluna, as horas com a condição 'SIM'.

Eu fiz um CASE WHEN nos históricos que devem ser 'NÃO', eo ELSE no restante para que seja 'SIM'.
E na minha WHERE, coloquei para mostrar apenas as horas onde a condição é 'SIM'.

**Como eu faço para colocar em outra coluna, as horas com a condição 'NÃO' ??**

Segue o select:

```
SELECT
ROUND(HORAS_TOTAIS,3) HORAS_IMPRODUTIVAS_PPR
FROM(
SELECT
(TEMPO_APONTADO_SEGUNDOS /3600) HORAS_TOTAIS,
CASE CD_HISTORICO
             WHEN 3 THEN 'NÃO'
             WHEN 10 THEN 'NÃO'
             WHEN 11 THEN 'NÃO'
             WHEN 16 THEN 'NÃO'
             WHEN 18 THEN 'NÃO'
             WHEN 20 THEN 'NÃO'
             WHEN 27 THEN 'NÃO'
             WHEN 28 THEN 'NÃO'
             WHEN 29 THEN 'NÃO'
             WHEN 31 THEN 'NÃO'
             WHEN 32 THEN 'NÃO'
             WHEN 33 THEN 'NÃO'
             WHEN 38 THEN 'NÃO'
             ELSE 'SIM' END CONTABILIZA_PPR
FROM APONTAMENTO_ORDEM_SEQ)
WHERE CONTABILIZA_PPR = 'SIM'
```

[image: RESULTADO DA QUERY]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que entendi acredito que essa tabela derivada não é necessária, acho que você pode utilizar um Case para cada coluna. Segue uma sugestão para testes:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN CD_HISTORICO NOT IN 
            (3, 10, 11, 16, 18, 20, 27, 28, 29, 31, 32, 33, 38) 
        THEN ROUND(TEMPO_APONTADO_SEGUNDOS / 3600, 3) 
    END as HORAS_IMPRODUTIVAS_PPR,
    CASE WHEN CD_HISTORICO IN 
            (3, 10, 11, 16, 18, 20, 27, 28, 29, 31, 32, 33, 38) 
        THEN ROUND(TEMPO_APONTADO_SEGUNDOS / 3600, 3) 
    END as NAO
FROM APONTAMENTO_ORDEM_SEQ
```

Comment: Opa, desculpe. Muito obrigado mestre @imex !!!